# 3 monitors work on Windows but not Ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot, multiple-monitors, hdmi

I am dual booting [this](https://www.bestbuy.com/site/hp-omen-16-1-qhd-gaming-laptop-intel-core-i7-16gb-memory-nvidia-geforce-rtx-3070-1tb-ssd-ceramic-white/6479084.p?skuId=6479084) laptop with Windows 11 and Ubuntu. I plan on almost always using Ubuntu. When I plug in my 2 additional monitors to the laptop using Windows they all work fine giving me 3 total displays. When I do it on Ubuntu however, only one of the monitors works giving me only 2 displays. I am using a thunderbolt 4 to hdmi for one and an hdmi to hdmi for the other. Whichever monitor I plug in using the thunderblot 4 always works and the one plugged in via hdmi always doesn't. Has anyone ever heard of something like this happening?
Thanks

Comment: I came to this website because I don't know very much about computers and found no answers to my question online. I installed Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS and don't know what those others questions mean.

Comment: You also don't have to come off like that. As the expert, if you think that having some other information would help you answer my question you could ask me to provide it rather than trying to make me seem like an idiot for not knowing to give it to you in the first place.

Comment: as i see, someone asked you for more explanation/information. Could you provide what type of ubuntu installation are you using? what kind of display driver are kernel loads?.

Comment: If you can provide these tips, we can agree to you and find some useful help for that. Take patience. (and don't forget to read [this](https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic))

Comment: On my laptop I have Nvidia Graphics card driving HDMI built into laptop and Thuderbolt 3 driving another HDMI via dongle with no problem. I haven't tried Thunderbolt 4 yet though.... When purchasing Thunderbolt dongle for HDMI one must do their research first for compatibility.

Comment: I have kernel 5.13.0-28-generic. I have an rtx 3070 gpu and I am using NVIDIA driver metapackage from nvidia-driver-510 (proprietary, tested). I installed Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS